# SQL returning incorrect number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this might seem like a simple question, but its answer has been eluding me for quite some time now. I'm trying to return the number of rows from the databases using the WHERE clause. My query is as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM nfl_current_season_games
          WHERE home_team = 'Indianapolis Colts'
          AND away_team = 'Chicago Bears'
          AND week = '1'";
```

I'm 100% sure there is such a row. I'm looking right at it in phpmyadmin. No matter if I execute the query with pure SQL in phpmyadmin or in a browser via a php script, it still returns a value of 0. I tried using the var_dump function for the $away_team and $home_team variables with php and they're both just fine. I don't know where to go from here because this seems so odd.

Does anyone have any tips or clues?

Thanks,

Lance

Comment: Maybe some (invisible) spaces for the data in your database?

Comment: I've thought that too. Any way to find out?

Comment: can you give the structure of the table and sample records?

Comment: You can use trim functions to strip spaces e.g. trim(home_team)

Comment: It's generally better to not just echo the variables you use in the query, but echo the query itself, you get the exact query you are executing that way and it may reveal some mistake you didn't realize you were making.

Comment: Run the SQL query with `SELECT *` (`NOT COUNT(*)`) and check the records selected with missing records...

Comment: Perhaps the problem is not with your query itself, but with your PHP code that gets the results.  Put a very basic query like `select * from nfl_current_season_games` into your code and see if you can get the results from that.

Comment: Well, depending on what the away_team and home_team are set to, I can get a correct number of rows. for example, there's a row where the away_team is set to 'New England Patriots' and the home_team is set to 'Miami Dolphins' and week is '5', that time, the query works. It's weird, sometimes the query returns the right num of rows and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: After some further review, I noticed that the week column doesn't have its collation set. Could that be an issue?

Comment: This is one reason to have a *Dimension Table*; Such as a table called `team`, with fields `(id, name, park_name, etc, etc)`.  Then your *Fact Tables* just uses the `id`s of the teams instead of the names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably have blank stapces or a collation issue in one of the column.

I suggest you run the query with one condition at a time and try to find out which one is causing the issue.

When you find out, paste it here to see if we can help

**EDIT:**

try to do something like (not sure about the mysql syntax, but the idea is to trim to remove blanck spaces and send it to upper):

```
UPPERCASE(TRIM(away_team)) = 'CHICAGO BEARS'
```

Comment: I agree.  Try `WHERE week = '1'` and check if you get the right results.  Then try `WHERE away_team = 'Chicago Bears' AND week = '1'`, etc, etc.

Comment: Isn't it true that trailing spaces are not considered in MySQL string comparisons?

Comment: Okay. I did it. It's def not the 'week' column that's the issues. Rather, it's the home_team and away_team columns. Beyond that, I don't know what's causing any problems as the php variables are exactly what they need to be in order for the correct number of rows to be returned.

Comment: Unless there you expect *actual* variation in the data, you should not add extra string manipulations like this, which will only slow things down.  Instead, just correct the value if it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it:

The Indianapolis Colts played an away game against the Chicago Bears on week 1.

http://www.colts.com/team/season-schedule.html

Sometimes it isn't a code problem!

Answer (score 0):

Is the data type of 'week' column is string/character?
if it is not then just give the value 1 without quote,otherwise (giving in quotes) would have been interpreting it as string/character.
Try this query:

> $query = "SELECT COUNT(*)
>
> FROM nfl_current_season_games
>
> WHERE home_team = 'Indianapolis Colts'
>
> AND away_team = 'Chicago Bears'
>
> AND week = 1 ";